# Why IntelliJ cannot see classes generated from .xsd file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, soap, xsd

I was following instructions from website https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ to create SOAP producer in Spring Boot. I tried to do the same project as it is on the website (so I used the same build-gradle and xsd files) after trying to create my own, but I cannot import class Country for example. When I downloaded the project from git everyting works fine. In addition, in downloaded project package that conatins classes it is marked as 'library root'. I used only gradle build task to generate these classes. What I did wrong?

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// tag::xsd[]
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "src/main/resources/countries.xsd"

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source", includeantruntime: false,
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// end::xsd[]

// tag::jaxb[]
configurations {
    jaxb
}

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-producing-web-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
// end::jaxb[]

// tag::dependencies[]
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1'
    jaxb("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11")
    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
// end::dependencies[]
```

countries.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"
           targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="currency">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @beata check whether Country class in this project location target/generated-sources/jaxb/